# Performing an action after a certain amount of clicks, e.g.showing a picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, counter

I've got a click counter and some functions, how can I define, that after/with the e.g. 10th click a function should be executed? Using HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Tried to add an `if`-clause to my click counter function in javascript in HTML, activating a function that was supposed to play a sound. But I did it wrong, it didn't work-

```
var clicks = 0;
function counting() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks; 
}


<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks"></a></p>
```

Click counter. 
Why can't I add:

```
if (clicks == 10) playSound();
```

To then let the sound play using:

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  function playSound() {
  audio.currentTime = 0;
  audio.play();}
```

The audio is defined with the ID audio in HTML.

Comment: Please for the next question you can created a jsfiddle. The solution that you needs [is here](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/jorgsuau/az2d7bc6/36/) Don't forget read about on click events in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your mistake** was instead of **"==="** you used **"=="**

```js
var clicks = 0;
function counting() {
  clicks++;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;   
  if (clicks === 10) {
    playSound();
  }
}
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  function playSound() {
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
  }
```

```html
<p onclick="counting();">Clicks: <a id="clicks"></a></p>
<audio id="audio" controls="">
  <source src="https://www.html-seminar.de/downloads/musikausschnitt-mike-coustic-memories.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `eventListener` in order to count the clicks. 
See: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

If you'd use jQuery, the `click()` method may help. 
See: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

You can also use the `on()` method to bind multiple events at the same time.
See: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp

As for performing an action after a certain amount of clicks, you will likely need to incorporate either method within your counter. Hope this helps in some way!

Answer (score 0):

I would add an eventlistener for clicks and after each click it checks if the clickcounter is == 10;

```
Var counter = 0

document.getElementById("clicks").addEventListener(‚click‘, () => {
 Counter++

 if (clicks == 10) {
   playSound() 
 }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (instead `==` you can use e.g. `>=` to run function more than once)

```js
document.onclick = e=> msg.innerHTML= (++counter==10) ? playSound() : counter ;

function playSound() { return "Play sound/ show picture" }
let counter=0;
```

```html
<div id="msg">Click somewhere</div>
```